# RC delay only on negative input voltage transition

Tags: capacitor, bjt, delay, filtering

I would like to construct an RC delay circuit that has no filtering/delay when my gpio transitions to voltage logic high (Vlh) but does filter the voltage as the pin transition to voltage logic low (Vll).  Meaning I don't want the filtered value (orange) to filter the raw signal where the red x is but I do want the filtering where the black circle is below.

[image: graph]

So I have constructed a basic circuit that I think may do the trick.  But I would like to would this circuit accomplish the filtering I am hoping?  Is there something in the design that I am missing?

[image: circuit]

Comment: RC low pass filter with diode across R, cathode to capacitor. There will be a forward diode drop though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRWXvZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All this does is to charge capacitor Cd really fast, via mosfet Q1. That happens while input IN is low. This is contrary to what you asked for, but since IN comes from a microcontroller, just write software to handle the inversion.

When IN returns high, Q1 is turned off, and Cd is permitted to discharge gently through Rd.

Here are the input and output waveforms:

[image]
[image]